# Drupal 7: Field input generated by wizard

Tags: php, mysql, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal, but not new to PHP/MySQL/etc...

Problem:

I have several forms that are completed by the user when performing various actions (upload, edit, create, etc). One of the fields contains project information that needs to be input in a specific manner. To prevent human error, I'd like the field to be presented as a guided input. I could create each of the required fields on every type of form, but it seems more efficient to create one dynamic field and reference it on other forms. Is there a straightforward method of accomplishing this? Would creating a custom field type that stores array-based values achieve this?

Desired outcome:

A modular way to add a field into applicable forms that guides user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a custom field using hook_field_widget_info() and hook_field_widget_view() to make a textarea. The guided input is returned to the textarea with JS as a JSON string (this is the field that stores in the database). The JSON string is processed in JS for display in the formatter.